# How to avoid drawing a route when point is not in a road

Tags: google-maps, routes, maps, bing-maps, here-api

The First picture shows the real path 
And the Second one show the result given by rounting services 
(Here Maps or Bing maps)
any idea ? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to calculate a route with a point that isn't on a road, it will snap to the nearest road if one is within about 150 meters. There is no option to avoid this. I believe all major mapping platforms do the same thing.

Comment: is there any variable in the response that indicate if the route returned is an approximation ?

Comment: No, but you can take the first point in the route and calculate the distance from the start point you provided.

Comment: try to use their route matching service to snap your GPS points to a proper location.